# No me aparece la carpeta "www" en la carpeta de proyecto

Tags: ionic

Estoy siguiendo un [tutorial de ionic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QepxfadRc3Y&list=PLYPjmy5IVxT-7FV0uzpG2izFhGoE0Hq2y&index=5) de como hacer tu primera App y no me aparece la carpeta "www" que contiene las carpetas "css", "img", "js", "lib" y "templates". Si veis el video en el momento 1:57, a la izquierda se ve que le aparecen esas carpetas.
No entiendo porque no me aparecen, yo he introducido el comando: `ionic start RedditApp` y a partir de ahí se supone que se generan los mismos archivos y carpetas, no?
Bueno, os mando un pantallazo por si sirve de algo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible que se deba a que en una versión anterior, en la que fue desarrollado el tutorial, el generador de proyectos de Ionic generara una carpeta www, pero esos ficheros los tienes disponibles la carpeta src.
[Estructura proyecto - Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/project-structure/)

EDIT:
El problema es que en el tutorial está usando la versión 1 de Ionic, la que se basa en AngularJS, hoy en día, Ionic usa Angular 2+.
Para generar un proyecto con la versión 1 de Ionic has de usar el modificador **--type ionic1** es decir: `ionic start RedditApp --type ionic1`

Comment: Buen consejo! He encontrado el archivo "index.html" en la carpeta src.

Comment: Pero no encuentro el archivo "app.js"

Comment: He encontrado todos los archivos que necesito pero están en distintas carpetas

Answer (score 2):

En la versión de ionic 3.20.0 me funcionó la siguiente línea

```
ionic start nombre_apps blank --type=ionic-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

He descubierto que si voy a la carpeta donde tengo alojado mi proyecto, desde la línea de comandos y tecleo `ionic serve` se me genera la carpeta `www`